# twitch api を用いてアーカイブ動画のコメントを取得したい

Tags: python, webapi

実行環境:
google colabratory
python 3.7.12

[Twitch配信アーカイブのコメント流量を可視化してみた](https://qiita.com/kanekom/items/42ed3cd079fa5409ae58)

を参考にして

```
import requests
import json
client_id='my_client_id'
video_id='target_video_id'
url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/v5/videos/' + video_id + '/comments?content_offset_seconds=0'
headers = {'client-id': client_id}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
row_data = r.json()
print(row_data)
```

というコードを書きました。

例えば↓の動画のコメントを取得したいとして
https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1114915638

video_idに1114915638を代入して実行してみても
`{'error': 'Not Found', 'status': 404}`
が返ってきてしまいます。

これが起こってしまう原因や対処法を知っている方いらっしゃったら教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: [ドキュメント](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/videos#get-video)を見ると`videos/<video ID>`形式でアクセスするのはLegacy Twitch API v5のようですので、URLの`v5`を`kraken`にすればよさそうな気がします

`url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/videos/' + video_id + '/comments?content_offset_seconds=0'`

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
v5のところをkrakenに変えてみても同様に404が返ってきてしまいました...  
[ドキュメント](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/videos#get-video)に書いてある通りにヘッダーに`Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json`を加えたとしても、CLIでcurlコマンドをコピペしてclient_id,video_idのみを変更して実行したとしても同様に404が返ってきてしまいます...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私も配信アーカイブを取得しようとしましたが、同じく Not Found となりました。現時点で返ってくる json には以下の文章が含まれています。

> The v5 API is deprecated and will be shutdown on February 28, 2022. Applications
> that have not accessed v5 before July 15, 2021 no longer have access to v5. For more information on the v5 API shutdown plan, see https://blog.twitch.tv/2021/07/15/legacy-twitch-api-v5-shutdown-details-and-timeline/ and the Twitch API documentation at https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api.

Twitch API v5 (https://api.twitch.tv/v5/*) は2022年2月28日に利用不可になるようで、少なくとも2021年7月15日よりも後に作成されたデベロッパーアプリケーションでは既に v5 API は利用できなくなっています。

また、現時点で最新の Twitch API Helix (https://api.twitch.tv/helix/*) には残念ながら配信アーカイブのコメントの取得する機能はないようです。
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-videos

ただし、Twitch の Web サイトでは現在も v5 の API を利用してアーカイブのコメントを表示しており、現状 Twitch 自身の Client-ID (kimne78kx3...) を用いることでのみコメントは取得できるようです。

グレーな手段になるので明言は避けますが、いくつか参考になるリンクを添付します。
https://thomassen.sh/twitch-api-endpoints/
https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink/issues/2680#issuecomment-552041482